# Fixed element under iOS navigation toolbar

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I have a fixed navigation element at the top of a page which I am trying to move whenever the iOS safari navigation (URL address) toolbar appears such that it is not covered by it.

I am deriving the height of the toolbar by first acquiring the real page height using an element with height `100vh`. The difference between this height and `window.innerHeight` is the height of the toolbar.

The problem, however, is that `top: 0` is sometimes covered by the toolbar, and sometimes it is just after it. This means that I cannot just set `top` to the height of the toolbar; It will work some times but not every time, depending on how the toolbar spawns.

Any ideas on how I might figure out when the `top: 0` is covered by the toolbar and when it is not?

By the way, this is only a problem in landscape mode. In portrait, `top: 0` is never covered by the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. You have to monitor the last scroll direction.

If the last scroll direction is `up` then `top: 0` is never covered by the toolbar.

If the last scroll direction is `down` then `top` should be `top: Math.min(toolbarHeight, window.pageYOffset)`